# How search api for civicrm?

Tags: drupal

I installed 'search_api' module for drupal 7 and 'civicrm_entity' module.

BUT the prefix 'drupal_' is added automatically.

I get this error:

> PDOException : SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'pagamac_081.drupal_civicrm_campaign' doesn't exist: INSERT INTO
>   {search_api_item} (item_id, index_id, changed) SELECT t.id AS item_id,
>   :index_id AS index_id, 1 AS changed FROM {civicrm_campaign} t; Array (
>   [:index_id] => 154 ) dans
>   SearchApiEntityDataSourceController->startTracking() (ligne 208 dans
>   /var/www/html/sites/all/modules/contrib/search_api/includes/datasource_entity.inc).

Comment: Hi, please desribe what are you trying to achieve and where/when you get this error

Comment: i try to integrate solr with civicrm, i add 'civicrm entity' module to list me all the civicrm entity in index of solr. but I have a prefix in setting.php "drupal_" that will added when i save the index.. in other ways the table is {civicrm_contact} but it writed {drupal_civicrm_contact}